# mongodb $addToSet failure, specify full document to insert

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo-2.x

I've done a bit of research on this and haven't come across anything that jumps out at me immediately as what I'm looking for.

Say we have a document (or documents) in a collection that look something like this:

```
//First example document
{
  "_id": "JK",
  "letters": ["J", "K"]
}
//Second example document
{
  "_id": "LM",
  "letters": ["L"]
}
```

So I run a query like the one below to see if I have any matching documents and of course I don't so I expect to get null.

```
> db.example.findOne({"_id": "LM", "letters": {"$in": ["M"]}})
null
```

So I do an update and add "M" to the letters array on the documents (syntax may not be quite right):

```
> db.example.update({"_id": "LM"}, {"$addToSet": {"letters": "M"}})
```

I run the possibility of not having a matching _id, so the findOne would would also return null given the example documents in the collection for this query.

```
> db.example.findOne({"_id": "AB", "letters": {"$in": ["A"]}})
null
```

Based on the way I've constructed the above query, I get null back when "A" is not found in letters or the _id of "AB" is not found on any document. In this case I know that this document isn't in there because I know what is in the collection.

What I'd like to do is keep my update query from above with $addToSet and modify it to use upsert WHILE ALSO specifying the document to insert in the event that $addToSet fails due to the document not existing to cut down on database transactions. Is this possible? Or will I have to break up my queries a bit in order to accommodate this?

Because this information may influence answers:
I do my querying through mongo shell and pymongo.

mongo version: 2.6.11

pymongo version: 2.8

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: So after a break and a bit more digging, it seems setOnInsert does what I was looking for. I do believe that this probably solves my issue, but I've not had a chance to test yet.

Comment: Though mixing upserts and adding to arrays "can" be a problem, it is generally not so as long as you can live with what `$addToSet` does. So as long as your "query" does not "test" for the presence of the element to add in the array, then "upserts" work just fine. And let's face it, `$addToSet` isn't going to "add" anything if the element already exists. Also if this results in an "upsert", then it's just going to create an array with the element(s) specified. Only stronger rules with `$push` are a problem for a single update statement.

Comment: @BlakesSeven So this would mean that my thinking is correct in that if the query contains `$addtoSet` and `$setOnInsert` that a failure on `$addToSet` would result in the query doing an insert using whatever I had in `$setOnInsert`?

Comment: This is what I think you are missing here `db.collection.update({ "key": "something" },{ "$addToSet": { "array": "A" } },{ "upsert":  true })` is perfectly fine if key was not matched an then a new single element array would be created containing "A" when an upsert occured. Even `db.collection.update({ "key": "something" },{ "$setOnInsert": { "other": "B" }, "$addToSet": { "array": "A" } },{ "upsert" true })` is also fine. The only thing you **cannot** do is *also* specify the same path of "array" in any other update operator. But you should note that you don't have to here.

Comment: So yes `$addToSet` will happen regardless of upsert or not. If you don't actually want to add to the array on "upsert" then just do `{ "$setOnInsert": { "array": ["A"] }}`. And that of course **only** occurs on "upsert", as is basically implied by the operator. If you mean something else, then it is not very clear. Like I said, only `$push` needs some care when testing for array elements first ( a kind of "addToSet" ), and there are reasons why an "upsert" cannot be a single operation in this case. But there are "Bulk" methods to get around this.

Comment: @BlakesSeven that clarifies pretty well what I was looking for. If you wanted to put together an answer, I'll accept it :) Thanks very much for your help!